# Re-adding an event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am still relatively inexperienced with Javascript

Question...is it possible to re-add an event listener? I have a page I am trying to get to slide out of the browser window, but then back in on click, requiring (I think?) that I take off the re-add an event listener. my entire set up might be wrong. I hope i am asking the right question.

As of now it behaves properly until it comes time to re-add the event listener.

thoughts?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var $toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
  var $back_messages = document.getElementById('back_list');
  var swipeMotion = function() {
    var isOpen = $toggle.classList.contains('slide-in');

    $toggle.removeEventListener('click', swipeMotion);
    $toggle.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-out' : 'slide-in');
  };

  $toggle.addEventListener('click', swipeMotion);

  $back_messages.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var isOpen = $toggle.classList.contains('slide-out');

    $toggle.setAttribute('class', isOpen ? 'slide-in' : 'slide-out');

  });

  $toggle.addEventListener('click', swipeMotion);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="slide-in" id="toggle">

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <header>
          <h1>Abberant Artist - Paula Bailey UI Designer</h1>
        </header>
      </div>
      </a>
      <div class="row incoming_message">
        <icon>hi an icon of the "person sending the thing</icon>
        <div>
          <p> short description in gray-ish tones of what its about, with ellipses on the end... </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row incoming_message">
        <icon>About</icon>
        <div>
          <p> Hey, here's that info you wanted... </p>
        </div>
      </div>

<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: It certainly is possible, but it might not be neccessary. Removing the event listener can be useful if you don't want anything to happen anymore when you click the toggle element. But if the toggle needs to react to *every* click, then just leave it there.

Comment: Also note that currently you're adding the event listener on the toggle element twice.

Comment: Off topic: by convention, for some devs (not all), a `$` prefix on a variable (`$var`) indicates that it's a jquery object/collection.   Unlike other languages (php) you don't need to prefix all your variables with `$` and if you do, it makes the code that much harder to read.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove/re-add the event listener, but it's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do without the relevant css / html (eg what's `back_list`?)  Is your intention that you click #toggle to hide then #back_list to show?   Is #toggle visible all the time (looks like it might not be clickable at all after the first one).   You can also hide/show the elements so they can't be clicked.